# TFS2010: Publishing test results takes forever

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We have a TFS2010 instance that is hosted overseas. We have a proxy locally so pulling source code is really no problem. Even full gets are quite speedy. One issue that we are experiencing is that when an automated build completes it takes *forever* for the test results to be published back to the server. The entire build and test process takes about 5 minutes. The publishing of the test results takes an additional *10* minutes. Twice the time it took to get the source, build it, and run all 1500 unit tests!

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Comment: Is there a reason the build server isn't located on the site as the TFS server?  Once the build is complete you can copy the compiled output and deploy to local test servers as and when needed.

Comment: The main reason is convenience. The TFS server is located in a data center with strict regulations. The build server is local for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a build agent at your location and set a name filter in the build definition to always select that build agent.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear. The TFS server is remote while the build agent is local. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Then it's probably because the build definition has to store the results in the TFS database before reporting it to you; which means a round trip to the remote, central TFS server.